# Upload file to maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to upload file to my maven2 repository, but it can't

By the way I don't get where to fill my user name and password(credentials).

Yes, I saw official maven gradle manuals but unfortunately I can't get it.

```
artifacts {
    archives file: file('build/somefile.txt'), name: 'result', type: 'txt'
}

configurations {
    resultArchives
}

uploadResultArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "MY_SECRET_URL/nexus/content/repositories/test_kirill/")
        }
    }
}

artifacts{
    resultArchives file: file('build/somefile.txt')
}
```

Comment: There are two things. First what exactly is the message you get cause i don't see anything in your post...And furthermore your URL to your nexus looks strange? Is the intentional a different repository and named `test_kirill` or dou you use a SNAPSHOT or RELEASE repository ?

Comment: @khmarbaise The problem is I cant get any message.

This code is in android {} block.

Unfortunately I don't know anything about snapshot or release.

I have access to Admin panel and see that this repo is alive. (I put MY_SECRET_URL instead of **********)

Comment: @khmarbaise Maybe I'm just not sending this  file?